# Runtime Error thrown by HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, http

Hey guys I'm kinda new to coding but I'm giving it my best shot.  I've been following this login and registration tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). I downloaded his source code and added in my database information and it works with his project in eclipse.  But when I run it in my project it quits when I click "Login" or "Register". I went through the debugger using breakpoints and found that the error seems to be on this line:

```
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I'm honestly not sure what the problem is and could really use some help.  Please keep in mind since I am a beginner I may not understand some advanced functions/terms yet.  Below is my code for Login.java Register.java under my main package (brg.application.alarmmonitor) and DatabaseHandler.java JSONParser.java UserFunctions.java as a library (brg.application.alarmmonitor.library) along with some errors from the LogCat in Eclipse.

Login.java

```
package brg.application.alarmmonitor;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import brg.application.alarmmonitor.Dashboard;
import brg.application.alarmmonitor.Register;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import brg.application.alarmmonitor.library.DatabaseHandler;
import brg.application.alarmmonitor.library.UserFunctions;

public class Login extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
//private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
//private static String KEY_ERROR_MSg = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            Log.d("Button", "Login");
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Register.java

```
package brg.application.alarmmonitor;

import org.json.JSONException;


import org.json.JSONObject;

import brg.application.alarmmonitor.Dashboard;
import brg.application.alarmmonitor.Login;
import brg.application.alarmmonitor.R;

import brg.application.alarmmonitor.library.DatabaseHandler;
import brg.application.alarmmonitor.library.UserFunctions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Register extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
//private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
//private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reg_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
package brg.application.alarmmonitor.library;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "a8855590_alarm";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Getting user login status
 * return true if rows are there in table
 * */
public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    // return row count
    return rowCount;
}

/**
 * Re crate database
 * Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void resetTables(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
    db.close();
}

}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package brg.application.alarmmonitor.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

UserFunctions.java

```
package brg.application.alarmmonitor.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;

public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

private static String loginURL = "http://alarmmonitor.comyr.com/android_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://alarmmonitor.comyr.com/android_login_api/";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Register Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}

}
```

LogCat Errors

```
11-04 18:02:28.570: D/Button(1725): Login
11-04 18:02:28.579: D/dalvikvm(1725): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 7% free 3017K/3228K, paused 2ms+0ms, total 3ms
11-04 18:02:28.579: D/AndroidRuntime(1725): Shutting down VM
11-04 18:02:28.579: W/dalvikvm(1725): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d5a908)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at brg.application.alarmmonitor.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at brg.application.alarmmonitor.library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:38)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at brg.application.alarmmonitor.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:57)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native     Method)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-04 18:02:28.579: E/AndroidRuntime(1725):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know it's a lot of code, sorry about that but I wanted to make sure you had all the code you needed to help me solve my problem.  Thanks again!

Jonathan

EDIT:
OK so I tried to change Login.java to use AsyncTask and I looked up a few things saw I needed to use publishProgress but now when I hit login it just says "Logging in..." for a long time until finally quitting.  Here is the new code and errors:

Login.java

```
package brg.application.alarmmonitor;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import brg.application.alarmmonitor.Dashboard;
import brg.application.alarmmonitor.Register;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import brg.application.alarmmonitor.library.DatabaseHandler;
import brg.application.alarmmonitor.library.UserFunctions;

public class Login extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
//private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
//private static String KEY_ERROR_MSg = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
/**     btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            Log.d("Button", "Login");
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
**/


class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>  {

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog (Login.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... message) {
        loginErrorMsg.setText(message[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

        Log.d("Button", "Login");

        // check for login response
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                //loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                publishProgress(json.getString("loginErrorMsg"));
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Store user details in SQLite Database
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    // Clear all previous data in database
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));

                    // Launch Dashboard Screen
                    Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);

                    // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                    dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(dashboard);

                    // Close Login Screen
                    finish();
                }else{
                    // Error in login
                    //loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    publishProgress(json.getString("Incorrect email/password"));
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}

btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new LoginTask().execute();
    }
});         

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

LogCat Errors:

```
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/Buffer Error(2046): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/JSON Parser(2046): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
11-05 17:40:30.610: D/Button(2046): Login
11-05 17:40:30.610: W/dalvikvm(2046): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d2c908)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at brg.application.alarmmonitor.Login$1LoginTask.doInBackground(Login.java:93)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at brg.application.alarmmonitor.Login$1LoginTask.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-05 17:40:30.610: E/AndroidRuntime(2046):     ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You're calling a network process inside the main thread, an this is not (normally) permitted.
You should call getJSONFromUrl(...) in a separate thread.

You can call it using a raw thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        getJSONFromUrl(...);
    }
}
thread.start()
```

Or using an AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Take into account that you'll need to change your code to "wait" until getJSONFromUrl(...) is compelted, and then you can continue with the flow of your program.

Edit: I'll add a bit about how to continue with the flow. In your case you could do something like:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        Log.d("Button", "Login");

        // Here you should show a loading dialog or somthing, as this can take a couple o seconds

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        ContinueFlow(); 
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Where "ContinueFlow()" would be a method with all that now is below

```
JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);
```

As you can see, you must call all those other things in the UI Thread (thats the motive of the runOnUiThread )

Using an AsyncTask (wich I think is more clean) you don't have to mess with the ui thread (you just do all the network stuff inside doInBackground, and continue with the flow in the onComplete(...))

Comment: OK I'll give that a try sorry if I sound ignorant but what would be put in the parenthesis where the ... is? I have the url listed in UserFunctions.java Also what's weird though is that it works fine in the source code project I downloaded from androidhive.info

Comment: Oh I just put for being a bit lazy, it's just the same parameters of the original method (loginURL, params). And about it working in other project, as I remarked, this is not normally permitted. There is a way to bypass this by removing the limitation (don't remember how, you can google it), but it's stringly discouraged, coz playing with network stuff inside the you thread will block the UI until the request is completed (and you cannot now how much it'll take)

Comment: so i just need to add that code in place of 
`JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);`
 under both 
`public JSONObject loginUser(...)`
and
`public JSONObject registerUser(...)` ?

Comment: OK i added that to my Login.java and it came with a bunch of errors...did i add it to the wrong class or something? sorry i'm just confused i think to help me understand it better would it be easier to just use the AsyncTask even though i'm not familiar with it?

Comment: I think the AsyncTask is best for me to learn and use in the future since it is the better, and cleaner option since I do generally like my programs cleaned up and polished.  The only problem I think is that since I am still a beginner to eclipse, java, and android development in general, I'm not entirely sure I understand how to properly use AsyncTask with what I'm trying to do.  If you have any tips or anything to help me out that would be much appreciated! Thanks, Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Android forbids the usage of network operation from the main thread of the application : [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

My advice is to use [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in order to perform yoour network operations.